# Use msgBox in appscript macro on iPad

Tags: ios, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet that has a macro and I would like to ask a yes/no question

```
var res = Browser.msgBox('Change defaults?', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
```

Works fine on my windows machine but I **need** it to run it on an ipad, The question never appears, it there a work around where I can ask a question and have it appear on the ipad

Code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var res = Browser.msgBox('Change defaults?', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Try using SpreadsheetApp.getUi()

Comment: getUi doesnt show up on the ipad either.

Comment: The we will need to see you code so please provide [mcve]

Comment: Check out this app scripts documentation link on  alerts and prompts best practices.   Calling a dialogue box from within google sheets should be OS / Browser agnostic.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs

Comment: So how can I bring up a dialog box inn google sheets that will show up in iOS. That link doesn’t give any info on it